# How to mock SerialDataReceivedEventArgs

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I have a peripheral driver that uses the serial port to communicate with the peripheral device. I want to unit test this driver and tried to mock the serial port. Therefore I created a wrapper for the framework type SerialPort to have it implement an interface:

```
public interface IScannerPort
{
    Handshake Handshake { get; set; }
    bool IsOpen { get; }

    event SerialDataReceivedEventHandler DataReceived;

    void Close( );
    void Open( );
    string ReadLine( );
}
```

Now I created a mock using moq:

```
Mock<IScannerPort> scannerPort = new Mock<IScannerPort>( );
```

I then want to raise the `DataReceived` event. But SerialDataReceivedEventArgs doesn't let me set the EventType property. So I tried to mock SerialDataReceivedEventArgs as well, ending up with

```
Mock<SerialDataReceivedEventArgs> args = new Mock<SerialDataReceivedEventArgs>();
args.SetupProperty(a => a.EventType, SerialData.Eof);
```

But the second line raises a NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: a => a.EventType

How can I raise the event? Or how can I mock the event args?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The SerialDataReceivedEventArgs doesn't necessarily be mocked. One can create an instance of it using reflection:

```
ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof (SerialDataReceivedEventArgs).GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null,
    new[] {typeof (SerialData)},
    null);

SerialDataReceivedEventArgs eventArgs = 
    (SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)constructor.Invoke(new object[] {SerialData.Eof});
```

Then the event can be raised on the mocked instance using the "real" instance of the vent args:

```
scannerPort.Raise( s => s.DataReceived += null, eventArgs );
```

Answer (score 3):

I think i may have partly solved your problem by answering how to raise the event, as follows:

```
  var mockedScannerPort = new Mock<IScannerPort>();

            mockedScannerPort.Setup(sp => sp.ReadLine())
                             .Returns("123")
                             .Raises(sp => sp.DataReceived += null, new object[] { this, It.IsAny<SerialDataReceivedEventArgs>() });

            bool mockEventWasInvoked = false;
            mockedScannerPort.Object.DataReceived += (sedner, e) => mockEventWasInvoked = true;
            var retVal = mockedScannerPort.Object.ReadLine();

            Assert.AreEqual( "123", retVal );
            Assert.IsTrue(mockEventWasInvoked);
```

Mocking SerialDataReceivedEventArgs is a bit tricky, since it doesnt have a default constructor. I'll try a workaround shortly.

**EDIT:** Thanks @PVitt for providing the workaround for stubbing SerialDataEventArgs. Posting this here just for the sake of completeness.

```
[Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            var mockedScannerPort = new Mock<IScannerPort>();

            var constructor = typeof(SerialDataReceivedEventArgs).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { typeof(SerialData) }, null);
            var eventArgs = (SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)constructor.Invoke(new object[] { SerialData.Eof });

            mockedScannerPort.Setup(sp => sp.ReadLine())
                             .Returns("123")
                             .Raises(sp => sp.DataReceived += null, new object[] { this, eventArgs });

            bool mockEventWasInvoked = false;
            SerialDataReceivedEventArgs ea = null;
            mockedScannerPort.Object.DataReceived += (sedner, e) =>
                                                         {
                                                             mockEventWasInvoked = true;
                                                             ea = e;
                                                         };

            var retVal = mockedScannerPort.Object.ReadLine();

            Assert.AreEqual( "123", retVal );
            Assert.IsTrue(mockEventWasInvoked);
            Assert.IsNotNull( ea );
            Assert.AreEqual( ea.EventType, SerialData.Eof );
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I fear the crucial point is missed out. The event handler depends on SerialDataReceivedEventArgs.EventType which cannot be mocked (well, I hope, it can :) )